# Swift type comparison against stored type

Tags: swift, types

I have a class that collects Types into an array, then decides whether an object is of one of the types:

```
struct Item: Hashable {}

class TypeChecker {
    let typeCollection: [Any.Type] = [Item.self]
    
    func acceptObject(_ object: Any) -> Bool {
        typeCollection.contains(where: { type(of: object) == $0 })
    }
}

let checker = TypeChecker()

let object1: Item = Item()
checker.acceptObject(object1) // returns true

let object2: AnyHashable = Item()
checker.acceptObject(object2) // returns false
```

In the simplified snipped above, explicitly typed `object1` works correctly, however, abstractly typed `object2` fails. What gives? How would I fix the TypeChecker?

Comment: In the second case you have declared the object to be of type AnyHashable so the compiler will accept any type of object that conforms to AnyHashable and will treat it as AnyHashable and not as Item. Note that `let object3 = Item()` will return true

Comment: Interestingly your function will had return correct result if instead of `AnyHashable` you had a protocol type. (see the last part of [type(of:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2885064-type) documentation) Apparently this doesn't work because `AnyHashable` is a concrete type that `Item` struct doesn't actually implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Approach 1: When acceptable types are known at compile time.

Create a marker protocol and add conformances for acceptable types:

```swift
protocol AcceptableForSomeActionType { }

extension Item: AcceptableForSomeActionType { }

class TypeChecker {
    func acceptObject(_ object: Any) -> Bool {
        object is AcceptableForSomeActionType
    }
}
```

### Approach 2: When acceptable types are known at runtime.

Create a protocol for container types that provides real object type.

```swift
protocol ObjectContainer {
    var objectType: Any.Type { get }
}

extension AnyHashable: ObjectContainer {
    var objectType: Any.Type { type(of: base) }
}

class TypeChecker {
    private let typeIdentifiers: Set<ObjectIdentifier> = [ObjectIdentifier(Item.self)]

    func acceptObject(_ object: Any) -> Bool {
        let objectType = (object as? ObjectContainer)?.objectType ?? type(of: object)
        return typeIdentifiers.contains(ObjectIdentifier(objectType))
    }
}
```